# Second keyframe in UIView.animateKeyframes not getting called

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation

Currently there are 2 CGAffineTransform key frames added to the UIView.animateKeyframes. For some strange reason the second keyframe's animation doesn't appear to happen. It just jumps right back to the starting position after the animation completes.

```
UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 3, delay: 0, options: [], animations: {

  UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 1, animations: {
    let scaledBy = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    self.firstView.transform = scaledBy.translatedBy(x: 120, y: 20).rotated(by: CGFloat.pi/2)

  })

  UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 1, relativeDuration: 1, animations: {
    let scaledBy = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.5, y: 1.5)
    self.firstView.transform = scaledBy.translatedBy(x: 40, y: 60).rotated(by: -CGFloat.pi/2)
    self.firstView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -CGFloat.pi/2)

  })

}, completion: {_ in})
```

Comment: Did you put a break point to validate that the second animation is actually not happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this is very old question. I hope my answer will be helpful though. The issue here is because you didn't get the meaning of `relativeStartTime` and `relativeDuration` parameters. The key word here is `relative`. It means that all your inner animations, added via `UIView.addKeyframe` function should happen between 0 and 1.

Because this call will create a kind of **timeline**

```
UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 3, delay: 0, options: [], animations: {

}, completion: {_ in})
```

This timeline runs from 0 to 1 (0% to 100%). Which means that **relative** duration of any animation can't be more than 1 and **relative** start time also can't be more than 1.

Comment: Did not know relative meant that. Thanks for clearing that up!